# How to fetch application specific url's by using wireshark in Windows-8/10?

Tags: wireshark

Its my first time using wireshark and I am encountered with one major problem i.e **How will i sniff url/api that a particular application/software is hitting which is installed in Windows-8/10 by using wireshark?**. Currently I am receiving a lot of url's and it is not possible to filter them out by any way. So i want to know is there any way to do that for a particular application like by setting some filters, etc. Please help me to solve this probelm.

What I have tried so far: **I have already tried by setting filters for some ports but still there are a lot of url's and the port numbers that application will hit are not known yet.**